# Как удалить и заново создать определенную таблицу в EF6 Code-First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется EF6 Code-First. Иногда требуется удалить все записи в определенной таблице. Всю базу данных можно пересоздать так:

```
dbContext.Database.Delete();
dbContext.Database.Initialize(/*force*/ true);
```

, но при таком подходе удаляется вся база.

Так-же можно использовать `Truncate [TableName]` с последующим созданием таблицы на основе SQL выражения и дальнейшим сбросом "счетчика", но это (на мой взгляд) спорное решение. В этом случае необходимо самому, в зависимости от используемого провайдера, использовать строго определенные SQL выражения:

```
/* MS SQL CE, SQLite, MS Access и др. не поддерживают Truncate */
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ALTER COLUMN [Id] IDENTITY (1,1)
/* MS SQL */
TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]
/* DB2 */
TRUNCATE TABLE schemaname.TableName IMMEDIATE
```

При таком подходе удаление нескольких миллионов записей из таблицы происходит до вызова исключения тайм-аута:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

В связи со всем вышеперечисленным имеется вопрос: имеется ли возможность в Entity Framework 6 (Code-First) удалить/создать определенную таблицу именно средствами EF?

Comment: Я для изменения схемы/ наката каких то скрпитов использовал бы миграции.

Comment: А если SQL выполнить с помощью асинхронного метода? В любом случае это как-то неправильно удалять таблицу при работе приложения, это может потребоваться только при изменении модели - поэтому рекомендую воспользоваться миграциями...

Comment: @Андрей удаление таблицы с её последующим созданием необходимо для уменьшения времени удаления очень большого количества элементов.

Comment: @tym32167 можно ли использовать миграции для поставленной задачи?

Comment: @XelaNimed, возможно вы неправильно удаление выполняете, поэтому долго обрабатывается. Навскидку, первое что гуглится: https://habrahabr.ru/post/203214/

Comment: @XelaNimed Зависит от вашей задачи. Если удаление таблицы - это регулярное / плановое мероприятие, но сорояженное с выходом новый версий ПО, то не подходит, ибо новые миграции выходят с новой версией продукта. Что касается EF - оно не поддерживает Truncate оператор, потому вам в любом случае придется руками писать SQL, хоть в миграциях, хоть без них. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5972 или https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/673001/Entity-Framework-with-NET-Framework-using-Cs

Comment: Присоединяюсь к мнению @tym32167. Вопрос имеет две трактовки, от них зависит и ответ. Оба ответа уже по сути даны в предыдущем комментарии, разве что не оформлены как ответ.